# open a new page in the same window

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am still learning ASP.NET and I am trying to open a page in the same window. I only succeeded in opening the page in another tab, but I want the current window to change to the next.

this is my code.

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonRegistreerHier" runat="server"
            CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Registreer hier!!" 
            OnClick="buttonRegistreerHier_Click"
            OnClientClick="window.open('RegistratieForm.aspx', 'OtherPage');" 
            PostBackUrl="~/RegistratieForm.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `window.location.href='RegistratieForm.aspx'` instead of `window.open`.

Comment: @RobinAster please mark it as answer to honor efforts of fellow member

Comment: @Cris, to quote Homer Simpson, "The satisfaction of helping another human being is all the thanks I etcetera"